# set default selected db value in select element php laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
<td>
    <select name="setR" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
           @if($ap_detail['pr'])
        <option selected="selected" value="{{$ap_detail['pr']->setR}}">   
            @endif
            @for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
           {{$ap_detail['pr']->setR}} Days Later</option>
        <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}} Days Later</option>
            @endfor
     </select>
</td>
```

if value exist in databse it select by default that value

I tried above code its working fine but it select the db selected value but also show in looping list I mean if 4 comes from database it shows two 4 values it should be one 4 value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might help you. So in loop if your database value occurs then add `selected="selected"` to that option instead of printing that option differently.

```
<td>
    <select name="setR" class="form-control">
        <option value="">--Select--</option>
        @for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++)
            @if($ap_detail['pr'] && $ap_detail['pr']->setR == $i)
                <option selected="selected" value="{{$ap_detail['pr']->setR}}">{{$ap_detail['pr']->setR}} Days Later</option>
            @else
                <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}} Days Later</option>
            @endif
        @endfor
    </select>
</td>
```